# Linq Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I've tried for many hours now to create a Linq Query with distinct and orderby. In this [article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx) the general problem with this is described.
The only way i found a solution was to create a plain SQL Query

```
SELECT TOP (10) [DATA]
FROM TestResult
inner join TestResultRelated on TestResultRelated.TestResult = TestResult.ID
WHERE TestResultRelated.PATH = 'TestResultRelatedAdditionalData.SoftwareVersion'
AND TestResult.USER_LOGIN_NAME = 'emilwkj'
AND TestResultRelated.DATA != ''
group by TestResultRelated.DATA order by max([START_DATE_TIME]) desc
```

I don't need a solution to this exact problem, but here is an example on the problem:

```
Table 1:
ID | DateUsed | Version
1 | 01/01/2018 | 1.0
2 | 02/03/2018 | 1.1
3 | 05/05/2018 | 1.0
4 | 04/06/2018 | 1.4
```

In the table above, how would it be possible in LinQ to extract the 3 last used different softwareversions?

Can this be achieved in LinQ?

Comment: We need to see your C# code to be able to help i.e. your entity classes and DbContext. What you are trying to achieve should be fairly simple.

Comment: where is your linq code?

Comment: So the problem is that i need to find the top ten last used SoftwareVersions. And you can't order after a distinct in Linq or anything. I can't show you DBContext as this is internally for the company i work for. Sorry guys. But isn't it fairly simple to translate the SQL to LinQ, if its possible? You don't have to write the exact code for me. I have used LinQ for a long time.

Comment: Plz share your C# code so that we can help you.

Comment: Just updated the page. I can't give you original context, but my problem is better described with a little example now

Comment: are you kidding!!

Comment: @EmilWismannKirkebæk-Jensen why write that in LINQ? Create proper entities with relations and navigation properties and have the ORM generate the query. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. This would allow you to write `.TestResultRelateds.Where(tst=>tst.TestResult.User="whatever" && tst.Data!='').GroupBy(...)` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like this : (Update column name as per yours)

```
var query = (from c in TestResult
        join tbl2 in TestResultRelated on c.ID equals tbl2.TestResult 
        where c.USER_LOGIN_NAME = 'emilwkj' and tbl2.DATA != ''
        orderby tbl2.DATA
        group tbl2 by tbl2.DATA into g
        select new 
        {
            Id = g.Key.Id,
            Name = g.Key.Name,
            TestResultRelated = g
        })
        .Distinct()   //.Distinct(x=>x.someColumn) 
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.date);
        .Take(10)
```

Comment: Hmm, and where is `Distinct(x => ...)` method coming from?

Answer (score 0):

As we understand you are using efcore and DbContext heaving TestResult and TestResultRelated table.

Here is the code of problem that we understand from your question.

```
var db=new DbContext();
var result = (from a in db.TestResult
             join b in db.TestResultRelated on a.ID equals b.TestResult
             where b.PATH == "TestResultRelatedAdditionalData.SoftwareVersion"
             & a.USER_LOGIN_NAME == "emilwkj" & b.DATA!=" "
             group b by b.DATA into item
             orderby item.Max(e=>e.START_DATE_TIME) descending
             select item)
             .Take(10);
```